How to return DataFrame from flask view function and to another python request
Python 1 app is calling url to receive DataFrame.
ret = requests.post(url, json = myobj)

Another python 2 app flask view function is supposed to reurn Dataframe .
How to do because falsk function is not able to return Dataframe.

You can choose JSON as the format for the data.
With pandas.DataFrame.to_json the data frame is converted to JSON and can then be sent.
See also pandas.read_json to convert the JSON data back into a data frame.
from flask import Flask
import io 
import pandas as pd
import requests 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    data = {
        'Name': ['Gerald','Ben','Charlotte'],
        'Age': [12, 25, 31],
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Name', 'Age'])
    return app.response_class(
        df.to_json(orient='records'), 
        mimetype='application/json'
    )


@app.route('/retrieve')
def retrieve():
    r = requests.get(
        'http://127.0.0.1:5000/', 
        headers={'Accept': 'application/json'}
    )
    r.raise_for_status()
    df = pd.read_json(io.StringIO(r.text), orient='records')
    print(df)
    return ''

